# Twilio studio flow with main account and subaccounts

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-flex

I have a main account and several subaccounts for my clients. I want to make a main studio flow in the main account that can start studio flows in the subaccounts. When I start the main flow, it will have a "from" number, and I want to use that number to know which subaccount flow to start.
Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

In the way you are describing your use case, it is not possible to execute a flow in your subaccount, it is because the "From" parameter must be a phone number in your account, in this case in your parent account.

You can create a workaround using our custom parameters when you execute the flow, it can be like this:

```
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.studio.v2.flows('FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                .executions
                .create({parameters: {
                   phone: '+15558674444'
                 }, to: '+15558675310', from: '+15017122661'})
                .then(execution => console.log(execution.sid));
```

Please notice that this is a Javascript example, if you are using a different language, you can find more information in this reference https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/execution, or open a ticket with Twilio support.

After that, you can use connect call to widget (https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/connect-call) to transfer the call to your subaccount (to use connect call to, you need to execute Make Outgoing Call widget before).
You can access the subaccount's phone number with flow.data.MY_CUSTOM_VARIABLE, in my example it would be flow.data.phone.